# special cron expression: how to make an exception?

Tags: linux, cron

I made a cron to execute a task every tuesday at 3:50 AM - except a tuesday which coincides with the first day of the month:

```
50 3 * * 2 MyCommand
```

but I don't know how I can translate my exception into the cron syntax, any tips?

Comment: I think you need to put a wrapper script round your command that just refuses to run if the day of the month is the 1st.

Comment: that's what i was thinking about :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you put a conditional in your script?  I would do that.  And in your cron you can comment that it won't run on the first per your script directions

As an example, in bash you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

dayofmonth=`date +"%d"`
if [ $dayofmonth == "01" ];
then
# do not run, exit
exit
fi

# otherwise go on

echo "it is not the first"
```

So your cron would be

```
30 5 * * 2 /path/to/script # comment: script conditional in place to not run on the 1st
```

Comment: Thank you, i think this should resolve my problem, even if in another way

Comment: Yup, I think you'd have to do it this way. Hopefully you weren't tied to just doing it in cron. From what I know of cron you wouldn't be able to do an exception like that.  So you'd need to do the exception in the script.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "day of month" field to the range 2-31, effectively excluding the first day. This should do it:

```
50 3 2-31 * 2 MyCommand
```

Comment: Thanks, i think this should execute my command not every tuesday, but all the days between(2-31)and also every tuesday, is it ?

Comment: @user3196353 is correct, I think, in that the above answer would execute on 2nd-31st of each month, and on the 1st if that happened to be a Tuesday. The man page fron crontab says "Finally, if either the month or day of month is specified as an element or list, and the day of week is  also  specified as an element or list, then any day matching either the month and day of month, or the day of week, shall be matched."

Comment: Thanks, sorry, you guys are right and this answer should probably be down-voted accordingly.