# How to schedule crontab not to run this time else for every 5 mins

Tags: unix, cron

I need to run my script every 5 mins but not between 1:40 AM to 1:50 AM.

can you please help me :(

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [special cron expression: how to make an exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508099/special-cron-expression-how-to-make-an-exception)

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices basically.  The first is to make 2 separate contab entries.
This is fairly involved, but the next is one simple.

The second is to place lines like this close to the beginning of the script:

```
now=$( date '+%H  %M' | awk '{print int($1)*100 + $2}')
[[ $now -ge 140 && $now -le 150 ]]  && exit
```

and to have a crontab entry like:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 /path/to/my/script 2>/path/to/errorlog
```